# Split self-intersecting linestring into non-self-intersecting linestrings

Tags: python, python-3.x, shapely

I have a list of coordinates defining a line string that might intersect with itself:

```py
coordinates = [
    [0, 3],
    [0, 5],
    [4, 5],
    [4, 0],
    [0, 0],
    [0, 5],
    [2, 5]
]
```

How can I split the linestring into smaller linestrings so none of the linestrings intersects with itself?

- smallest number of linestrings
- line strings should have equal number of coordinates as possible

the desired outcome in this case would be:

```py
line0 = [
    [0, 3],
    [0, 5],
    [4, 5],
    [4, 0]
]
line1 = [
    [4, 0],
    [0, 0],
    [0, 5],
    [2, 5]
]
```

### My attempt

In my attempt so far I construct an intersection matrix using Shapely Linestrings to find the intersections:

```py
from shapely.geometry import LineString
from itertools import product, zip_longest
import numpy as np

def get_intersection_matrix(coordinates):
    linestrings = [
        (ix, LineString([c0, c1]))
        for ix, (c0, c1) in enumerate(zip(coordinates[:-1], coordinates[1:]))
    ]
    M = np.zeros((len(linestrings), len(linestrings)))
    for (ix0, ls0), (ix1, ls1) in combinations(linestrings, 2):
        if abs(ix0 - ix1) == 1: # ignore connecting segments
            continue
        if ls0.intersects(ls1):
            M[ix0, ix1], M[ix1, ix0] = 1, 1
    return M
```

which outputs what I call the "intersection matrix":

```py
>> get_intersection_matrix(coordinates)
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

That you can read as:

- segment 1 intersects with segment 5 and 6
- segment 2 intersects with segment 5 and 6
- segment 5 intersects with segment 1 and 2
- segment 6 intersects with segment 1 and 2

Also; I think that the number of "intersection clusters" indicate the number of linestrings: `no_clusters + 1`

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How can I split the linestring into smaller linestrings so none of the linestrings intersects with itself?

Comment: have you tried https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#validation.make_valid ?

Comment: thanks for the idea; but `shapely.make_valid(LineString(coordinates)) == LineString(coordinates)` outputs `True`

Comment: It is an approach but I get stuck splitting the matrix in almost equal boxes (where sum=0) around the diagonal

Comment: Why does `line1` start at `[0, 0]` instead of `[4, 0]`?  That way you skip the line segment between `[4, 0]` and `[0, 0]`

Comment: thats ok for my usecase, but maybe you are right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I solve it now... I changed my intersection matrix, so at no intersection the value is 1 and at any intersection the value is 0.

```py
def get_intersection_matrix(coordinates):
    linestrings = [
        (ix, LineString([c0, c1]))
        for ix, (c0, c1) in enumerate(zip(coordinates[:-1], coordinates[1:]))
    ]
    M = np.ones((len(linestrings), len(linestrings)))
    for (ix0, ls0), (ix1, ls1) in combinations(linestrings, 2):
        if abs(ix0 - ix1) == 1:  # ignore connecting segments
            continue
        if ls0.intersects(ls1):
            M[ix0, ix1], M[ix1, ix0] = 0, 0
    return M
```

```py
>> M = get_intersection_matrix(coordinates)
>> M
array([[1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1.]])
```

- any combination of split indexes is given by: `itertools.combinations(range(1, len(M)), nr_split_ixs)` where also `ix1 < ix2 < ... < ixn`

at one split index you get two squares that should not contain any 0's, and the squares can be optimized by a minimum sum!

This is a legal (but not the best) split with `split_ix = 4` and the sum of the two boxes is 16+4 = 20.
[image]

This is a better legal (no zeros) split where the sum of the two boxes is 9+9=18

[image]

The method to calculate the scored split indexes:

```py
def get_scored_split_ixs_combination(M, nr_split_ixs):
    ixs_scores = []
    for ixs in combinations(range(1, len(M)), nr_split_ixs):
        splitted_matrix = [
            M[i0:i1, i0:i1] for i0, i1 in zip((0, *ixs), (*ixs, len(M)))
        ]
        # check if no matrices have zeros
        if not all([(m > 0).all() for m in splitted_matrix]):
            # ilegal ixs combination
            continue
        ixs_scores.append((ixs, sum([m.sum() for m in splitted_matrix])))
    return ixs_scores
```

if the return is empty there are no legal options and you should increase the number of splits.

Now return the best split option by increment the number of splits:

```py
def get_best_split_ixs_combination(M):
    nr_split_ixs = 0
    while True:
        ixs_scores = get_scored_split_ixs_combination(M, nr_split_ixs)
        if ixs_scores:
            return min(ixs_scores, key=lambda x: x[1])[0]
        nr_split_ixs +=1

>> get_best_split_ixs_combination(M)
(3,)
```

And finally wrap it all together:

```py
def get_non_intersecting_linestrings(coordinates):
    M = get_intersection_matrix(coordinates)
    split_indexes = get_best_split_ixs_combination(M)
    return [
        coordinates[i1:i2]
        for i1, i2 in zip([0] + split_indexes, split_indexes + [len(coordinates)])
    ]
>> get_non_intersecting_linestrings(coordinates)
[[[0, 3], [0, 5], [4, 5]], [[4, 0], [0, 0], [0, 5], [2, 5]]]
```